# Why is my character counter not excluding spaces?

Tags: javascript, html

I am making a character counter with HTML, CSS, JS. I got the counter working, but I have a checkbox that should get the length of the input without the spaces, but it is not working. Please check my code and tell me what's wrong.

```js
function char_count(str, letter) {
  var letter_Count = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    if (str.charAt(i) == letter) {
      letter_Count += 1;
    }
  }
  return letter_Count;
}

function countChars(obj) {
  var length = obj.value.length;
  var output = document.getElementById("chars");
  var dis = document.getElementById("removeSpace");
  if (dis.checked) {
    var spaces = char_count(obj, " ");
    length = length - spaces;
    output.innerHTML = length + ' characters';
  } else {
    output.innerHTML = length + ' characters';
  }
}
```

```html
<h1> Character Counter </h1>
<textarea id="input" onkeyup="countChars(this)" placeholder="Enter your text here..." autofocus></textarea>
<input type="checkbox" id="removeSpace">
<label for="removeSpace" onclick="countChars(document.getElementById('input'))">Don't Include Spaces</label>
<span id="chars">0 Characters</span>
```

Comment: `obj` is your input, `obj.value` is the value. `char_count(obj.value, " ")`

Comment: thank you @Niet the Dark Absol i understand

Answer (score 0):

You could make the code more simpler. Moreover, you have placed the checkbox outside the label that has onclick="countChars(document.getElementById('input'))", that's why the condition dis.checked in js does not find the checkbox as checked. Place the checkbox inside the label.

The whole simplified code would be like this,

```
<h1> Character Counter </h1>
<textarea id="input" onkeyup="countChars(this)" placeholder="Enter your text here..." autofocus></textarea>

<label for="removeSpace" onclick="countChars(document.getElementById('input'))">
    <input type="checkbox" id="removeSpace">
    Don't Include Spaces</label>
<span id="chars">0 Characters</span>

<script>

    function countChars(obj) {
        var length = obj.value.length;
        var output = document.getElementById("chars");
        var dis = document.getElementById("removeSpace");
        if (dis.checked) {
            length = obj.value.replace(/\s/g, '').length
        }
        output.innerHTML = length + ' characters';
    }
</script>
```